# OpenAPI 3. Nest an array of objects within an object that has a value as the key

Tags: openapi

I am trying to work out how to model the following object according to the OpenAPI 3.0 specification

```
{
    "data": {
        "7or5g1ld2dk7blcdovu272uba1": [
            {
                "n_id": "e28a39df-d084-486d-8667-48a79affbe01"
            },
            {
                "n_id": "e28a39df-d084-486d-4432-48a79affbe01"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I think it's something like this but rather than the key being `id` it should be the value of the id.

```
    aai_create_request:
      properties:
        data:
          description: The data object.
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              description: The id of the AAI
              type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    n_id:
                      description: The unique id of the node to be shared
                      type: string
                      example: 7af7fdbc-a925-4334-8dbf-a8e53fba9d9f
```

How would I represent that?

Comment: Do you mean that the key which is `7or5g1ld2dk7blcdovu272uba1` in your example can be dynamic?

Comment: Yes the key is the value of the id and will change for each instance of the "AAI"